# onActivityResult() not called with two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I have two Fragments named HomeworkListFragment and HomeworkFragment.

BOTH INHERIT FROM -> Fragment

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),HomeworkPagerActivity.class);
i.putExtra(HomeworkFragment.EXTRA_HOMEWORK_ID, homework.getId());
startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_DELETE_HOMEWORK_ID);
```

This is how I start MyFragment from MyListFragment.

After I finish, I want to call this from MyFragment:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra(EXTRA_DELETE_HOMEWORK_ID, mHomework.getId());
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
//Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "deleting?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
//getActivity().finish();
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());
```

Back in MyListFragment I've implemented:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    if  (requestCode == REQUEST_DELETE_HOMEWORK_ID){
        String filename = data.getStringExtra(HomeworkFragment.EXTRA_DELETE_HOMEWORK_ID);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ID: "+filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
}
```

However, this method is never called!

I've declared them both in my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomeworkListFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeworkTabFragment"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeworkFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeworkListFragment"/>
    </activity>
```

Is part of the answer with: NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());

Is MyListFragment getting recreated?

Comment: you have to call getActivity().finish(); in the child Activity

Comment: So do I also call NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity()); in addition to that?

Comment: After making that edit, it still doesn't call onActivityResult(). No matter what combination I try. With both navigateupfromsametask and get activity().finish(); Neither does it. Is MyListFragment getting recreated?

Comment: try just for testing startActivityForResult from your Activity and see if Activity.onActivityResult is called

Comment: What do you mean? HomeworkListFragment is nested within another Fragment named HomeworkTabFragment. In turn, HomeworkTabFragment is nested within another fragment named HomeworkMain. So which activity should I call it from and how do I test to see if Activity.onActivityResult is called?

Comment: those fragments are not floating over the ocean but are attached to some Activity,  getActivity() tells which activity hosts a fragmant,  so override ther onActivityResult and call getActivity().startActivityForResult and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, I was missing out the line:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

I had referenced the wrong line previously and could not figure out why. Now I have it!